# Unexpected token error in MongoDB for aggregate and $match for multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I keep getting unexpected stage name error or unexpected token error in mongoDB

`db.movies.aggregate([{$match:{genre:{$all:['Comedy','Drama']},{year:{$gt:["$year",2005]}}}}])`

I want to find movies with genre as drama and comedy and release date after 2005 but this code doesn't seem to be working and keeps giving me unexpected token error or with a different code, unrecognized pipeline stage name: year error

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper query for your use case is something like this:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      genre: {
        $all: ["Comedy", "Drama"],
      },
      year: {
        $gt: 2005,
      },
    },
  },
])
```